# Get touched view Android's ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In version 22.2 of the `recyclerview-v7` support library, Google introduced the `ItemTouchHelper` to ease the drag/drop and swipe of items.

In my `RecyclerView`, I would like to enable those features on one `View`/part of the adapter item only, and not the complete item. Is there a way to limit the scope of `ItemTouchHelper` to a specific target? Or maybe get the touched `View` when `ItemTouchHelper.onMoved()` or `ItemTouchHelper.onSwiped()` are called to be able to filter the allowed `View`s there?

Comment: You want to drag around and swipe only a particular child of a RecyclerView item, or you want to drag/swip the whole item only when that child is touched?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ItemTouchHelper.startDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html#startDrag(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) to start a drag manually.

Your `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` should return false from `isLongPressDragEnabled()`. Then you can create an `interface` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` that let's the `Fragment`/`Activity` know about a long-press on your "handle" `View`.

To see an example of this, check out my `ItemTouchHelper` example project:

https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo

[RecyclerListAdapter](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/b6d2464c45/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fco%2Fpaulburke%2Fandroid%2Fitemtouchhelperdemo%2FRecyclerListAdapter.java) has the `OnStartDragListener` which notifies [RecyclerListFragment](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/b6d2464c45d8b504dbc17c473cdca271ded2bd80/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/RecyclerListFragment.java) that a drag should be started (calling `startDrag()`).

Answer (score 0):

[`onMove`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onMove%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder%29) method has a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder` parameter. `viewHolder.itemView` should be the touched view. If it is the view that you need to move, move it to the target object and let `onMove` method return `true` else `false`.

```
public abstract boolean onMove (RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)


Parameters
recyclerView    The RecyclerView to which ItemTouchHelper is attached to.
viewHolder  The ViewHolder which is being dragged by the user.
target  The ViewHolder over which the currently active item is being dragged.
```

Comment: I didn't know about `ViewHolder.itemView`, but it seems that it is the full `View` inflated in the adapter, not the child `View` that was touched. Is that correct?

Comment: ItemTouchHelper is used to provide callbacks for recyclerview's full items movement and ViewHolder.itemView is the full view of the item.

Comment: btw what would be the target view for your view that needs to be moved?

Comment: The while item `View` should move, but the movement should only be triggered if long clicked is made on a specific part of the item. Same for the swipe. The reason is that one of the child `View` has its own events, and I don't want it to interfere with the `ItemTouchHelper` events.

Comment: You should try attaching a long click listener to your specific part of the item that should trigger item movement. How do you intend to detect swipe on the specific part of the item? Is it large enough?